# Cookie's expires property cannot be inspected

Tags: javascript, cookies

I try to set a cookie in browser ( here chrome ver.41.xxx ) using debugger's console:

```
> document.cookie = 'cookie1=hans; expires=Fri, 03 May 2020 11:00:00 GMT;'
```

Then, I inspect the `.cookie` property:

```
> document.cookie 
> "cookie1=Hans"
```

Surprisingly, no `expires` section! Fiddler also reports the same when I refresh the page:

[image]

These are enough for me to believe that expires property is not set.
**But, I get more surprised when I see the cookie expires using [EditThisCookie](http://www.editthiscookie.com/) extension**

[image]

I tried to set the cookie using JavaScript in my code and exactly the same result!

**Question:** How can I make sure that the `expires` property of the cookie is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading from cookies, you will *only* be given the value of cookies which are valid for the current host, path, security setup, and time. Short of using a special browser add-on or browsing the file system (neither of which you can do from your own code), there is no way to get this info about a cookie. If it's there, it's not expired. That's just the way the cookie "API" was written.

In response to "*How can I make sure that the `expires` property of the cookie is set?*" - if you pass it, it's set. Using a [cookie library](https://github.com/JAAulde/cookies) to improve upon the browser's API can, however, help you get everything set with less fussy string manipulation.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. But how can an add-on like EditThisCookie report the expires?

Comment: It operates outside the parameters of in-browser scripting. I don't know the mechanics as I have not looked at the code in that piece of software, but I imagine it's using the filesystem to access the cookie data in the same way the browser does when deciding what cookies are valid.